# Which incoming path required GetLocalPath activity

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-sdk, workflow-activity, tfs-2013

I have TFS 2013. I need convert path like ConvertWorkItem in tfs 2012. But Workspace doesn't exist in TFs2013 default definition. SO, I discovered, That instead this activity Microsoft created GetLocalPath activity. I try in incoming path set different value:

> $/Project/Path/
>   or this way:
>   ($PublishDir)/Path/

No one of this example doesn't work. In result it set same value, that was setup in incoming. In my case works only physical path in build agent, like this:

> d:\BuildAgent\78\Path\

In this case I have two question:

1. Why need GetLocalPath Activity, If they doesn't convert path? In
   this case, I can setup path right in Execution Activity.
2. Maybe I set wrong value? I have many build agent in different servers, and I can't use one physical path in different server.

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I resolve the root and relative paths of TFS folders on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28157538/3744182) and [TFS 2013 convert server path to local path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34888350/3744182).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

`buildDetail.BuildServer.TeamProjectCollection.GetService(Of VersionControlServer).GetWorkspace(srcPath).Name`