# Get build agent folder path in tfs build

Tags: batch-file, tfs, build, tfsbuild

How to access TFS build agent folder path in using batchfile?

[image]

I am calling runscript tool from build workflow (calling windows batchfile). 
I tried to use the environment variable BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH ($(BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH), $env:BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH) but they dint give any result.
Need some assistance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used another workaround for this instead of getting by workspace. From `sourceDirectory` folder i drill down to find my solution project file, the path containing my solution project is the local directory path i need

From batchfile i call my exe and pass `%TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY%` as parameter.

```cs
string[] subdirectoryEntries = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory) 
// targetdirectory would be the input parameter from batch file`

for (int i = 0; i < subdirectoryEntries.Length ; i++)
{
     // My root folder always contains a specific folder with name MyFolder 
     // and a file Myfile.sln

     if (subdirectoryEntries[i].ToString().ToLower().Contains(@"MyFolder")) 
     {
          Console.Writeline("My source code path is " + targetDirectory);
     }   

     //Similarly I check for Myfile.sln and then get my path.             
}
```

This may be a very crude way, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The variable you are looking for is `TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY`. Please refer to the [XAML build documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh850448(v=vs.120)).

Comment: Hey Daniel, %TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY% gives me path till src folder but not the complete path. For the above screenshot in the question. It gives me path till C:\TFS_Build\src, but i would want till C:\TFS_Build\src\V9. Reason is i have multiple build branches.

Answer (score 0):

**TF_BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY**: The sources sub-directory of the build agent working directory. This directory contains your source code. For example: `C:\Build\BuildBot3\CoolApp\CIBuild\src`.

If you want to get `C:\TFS_Build\src\V9`, it's just **local path**: the path that you have mapped the server path to on your machine. There is not any built-in [TF_BUILD environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/hh850448(v=vs.120)#tfbuild-environment-variables) could achieve your requirement.

You could use TFS API to get the related info, first  get the workspace information for the build server's workspace, then do the get option, a sample code for your reference:

> ```
> // Get the workspace information for the build server's workspace
> var workspaceInfo = Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(sourcesDirectory);
>
> // Get the TFS Team Project Collection information from the workspace cache
> // information then load the TFS workspace itself.
> var server = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(workspaceInfo.serverUri);
> var workspace = workspaceInfo.GetWorkspace(server);
> ```
>
> Once you have a workspace, you can query it for the path mappings.  It
>   will do the necessary translation from server to local path based on
>   your workspace mappings.  For example:
>
> ```
> workspace.GetServerItemForLocalItem("C:\TFS_Build\src\V9");
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> workspace.GetLocalItemForServerItem("$/DEV/V9");
> ```
>
> This mechanism will only work, however, if your build definition
>   actually sets up the workspace to include these files.

More details please refer this similar question: [How do I resolve the root and relative paths of TFS folders on the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28157538/how-do-i-resolve-the-root-and-relative-paths-of-tfs-folders-on-the-server)

---

***update from OP:***

> From sourceDirectory folder i drill down to find my solution project
>   file, the path containing my solution project is the local directory
>   path i need

Comment: Thanks Patricklu, I used another workaround for this instead of getting by workspace. From sourceDirectory folder i drill down to find my solution project file, the path containing my solution project is the local directory path i need.

Comment: PatrickLu- I have added my solution and marked it as answer if you feel its worth a solution you please upvote so that it becomes easy for others viewing this question.